# Traversing arrays nested in objects to find matches

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have the following array, which contains a series of objects. Inside of each object is a property with an array.

```
const films = [
    {
    name: 'Ant-Man and the Wasp',
    genre: ['Action' , 'Adventure' , 'Sci-Fi' , 'Comedy']
  },
  {
    name: 'Sorry to Bother You',
    genre: ['Comedy' , 'Fantasy']
  },
  {
    name: 'Jurassic World: Fallen Kingdom',
    genre: ['Action' , 'Adventure' , 'Sci-Fi'],
  },
  {
    name: 'Incredibles 2',
    genre: ['Action' , 'Crime' , 'Drama' , 'Thriller']
  },
  {
    name: 'Deadpool 2',
    genre: ['Action' , 'Adventure' , 'Comedy']
  }
];
```

I'm trying to traverse through the object's array and find matches using the following code, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected. How I can find matches between objects based on genre?

```
for (let i = 0; i < films.length; i++) {
  let film = films[i];
  let genres = film.genre;

  for (let j; j < genres.length; j++) {
    if (genres[j] == "Action") {
      console.log('Match');
    } else {
      console.log('No Match');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think all the objects does not contain same property so you have to put condition may be?

Comment: Did yo mean for some properties to be called `dependencies` and other `genre`? Why are they different?

Comment: pro tips: you can use [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) for clarity instead of a loop, and you should check with uppercase or lowercase

Comment: typos galore. indeed all the array properties are meant to be genre. i updated it above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm working on the assumption that the two different property names is not a typo and that you have `genre` and `dependencies`.

Either way, you can do it with a one-liner:

```js
const films = [{name: 'Ant-Man and the Wasp',genre: ['Action' , 'Adventure' , 'Sci-Fi' , 'Comedy']},{name: 'Sorry to Bother You',genre: ['Comedy' , 'Fantasy']},{name: 'Jurassic World: Fallen Kingdom',dependencies: ['Action' , 'Adventure' , 'Sci-Fi'],},{name: 'Incredibles 2',dependencies: ['Action' , 'Crime' , 'Drama' , 'Thriller']},{name: 'Deadpool 2',dependencies: ['Action' , 'Adventure' , 'Comedy']}];

let actionflicks = films.filter(f => (f.genre || f.dependencies).includes( 'Action'))
console.log(actionflicks)
```

As for your code, it's not a bad start, but it is failing with errors. You should get in the habit of looking at the console when things aren't working. It will point you toward what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks for not using ugly nested fors!

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of typos in this code. Correct code should be:

```js
const films = [
    {
    name: 'Ant-Man and the Wasp',
    genre: ['Action' , 'Adventure' , 'Sci-Fi' , 'Comedy']
  },
  {
    name: 'Sorry to Bother You',
    genre: ['Comedy' , 'Fantasy']
  },
  {
    name: 'Jurassic World: Fallen Kingdom',
    genre: ['Action' , 'Adventure' , 'Sci-Fi'],
  },
  {
    name: 'Incredibles 2',
    genre: ['Action' , 'Crime' , 'Drama' , 'Thriller']
  },
  {
    name: 'Deadpool 2',
    genre: ['Action' , 'Adventure' , 'Comedy']
  }
];

for (let i = 0; i < films.length; i++) {
  let film = films[i];
  let genres = film.genre;

  for (let j = 0; j < genres.length; j++) {
    if (genres[j] == "Action") {
      console.log('Match');
    } else {
      console.log('No Match');
    }
  }
}
```

As Mark pointed out, some objects in array have properties called "dependencies" which should be called "genre". Also "for (let j; j < genres.length; j++) {", j must be assigned a value.

Answer (score 1):

Apply condition before looping the genres

```
for (let i = 0; i < films.length; i++) {
  let film = films[i];
  let genres = film.genre;

  if (genres != undefined){
  for (let j; j < genres.length; j++) {
    if (genres[j] == "Action") {
      console.log('Match');
    } else {
      console.log('No Match');
    }
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: It might work better if you initialize `j` to `0` in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The key in other objects are different.In the last 3 objects the key is 'dependencies' instead of 'genre' .So when traversing last 3 objects `films[i].genre` is `undefined` ,so there will be a error at `genres.length`

If you want also traverse through 'dependencies' then use the following code

```
for (let i = 0; i < films.length; i++) {
 let film = films[i];
 let genres = film.genre||film.dependencies;//if no 'genre' then check 'dependencies' 
 if(!genre){continue;}//if there is none then skip the loop
 for (let j; j < genres.length; j++) {
  if (genres[j] == "Action") {
   console.log('Match');
  } else {
   console.log('No Match');
  }
 }
}
```